# Fast way to get an 2d array with some columns and in a certain order from an original matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix and i desire to mount another matriz with a few columns and in a specific order of columns. See example:

**Full Matrix**

```
 0  1  2  3  4
[15 22 17 19 14]
[34 67 39 70 65] 
[56 9  26 57 90]
[11 35 81 44 33]
```

**Desired Columns**

```
listIdsColumns = [3, 1, 0]
```

**Resulting Matrix**

```
 3  1  0
[19 22 15]
[70 67 34]
[57 9  56]
[44 35 11]
```

The following code performs the operation successfully. Someone suggest a more optimized alternative solution in relation to the running time and number of lines? Thanks.

```
def constructPartialMatrix(listIdsColumns):
    matrixPartial = np.array(matrixFull[:, listIdsColumns[0]])
    listIdsColumns.remove(listIdsColumns[0])
    while listIdsColumns:
        column = np.array(matrixFull[:, listIdsColumns[0]])
        listIdsColumns.remove(listIdsColumns[0])
        matrixPartial = np.column_stack((matrixPartial, column))
    return matrixPartial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can simply select "interesting" columns:

```
In [41]: a
Out[41]:
array([[15, 22, 17, 19, 14],
       [34, 67, 39, 70, 65],
       [56,  9, 26, 57, 90],
       [11, 35, 81, 44, 33]])

In [42]: a[:,[3,1,0]]
Out[42]:
array([[19, 22, 15],
       [70, 67, 34],
       [57,  9, 56],
       [44, 35, 11]])
```

it should work also with matrixes:

```
In [44]: a
Out[44]:
matrix([[15, 22, 17, 19, 14],
        [34, 67, 39, 70, 65],
        [56,  9, 26, 57, 90],
        [11, 35, 81, 44, 33]])

In [45]: a[:,[3,1,0]]
Out[45]:
matrix([[19, 22, 15],
        [70, 67, 34],
        [57,  9, 56],
        [44, 35, 11]])
```